# SQL Server - Replace nulls total with names inside the table

Tags: sql-server

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKkRm.jpg)

I have the piece of code below, where I cannot figure how to replace the NULL values with products  names inside the table, I used case statements but created an additional column and is not the result that I am looking for:

Data Set

```
Apparel  Brand    TotalPrice
-------  -----    ----------
Jeans    Charly      2249.85 
Jeans    Lee            0.00 
Jeans    Lee        10497.90 
Jeans    NULL       12747.75 
Shirt    Gucci      34539.90 
Shirt    Tommy H     1070.00 
Shirt    NULL       35609.90 
NULL     NULL       48357.65
```

Query

```
SELECT Apparel, Brand, SUM (COALESCE((Quantity * Price),0)) AS TotalPrice
FROM #Sales
GROUP BY ROLLUP (Apparel, Brand)
```

Desired Result

```
Apparel Brand                     TotalPrice
Jeans   Charly                       2249.85
Jeans   Lee                             0.00
Jeans   Lee                         10497.90
Jeans   **SubToTal jeans**          12747.75
Shirt   Gucci                       34539.90
Shirt   Tommy H                      1070.00
Shirt   **SubToTal Shirts**         35609.90
**Grand Total** **Grand Total**     48357.65
```

Any Help will be really appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any `NULL` values here.  Can you post either a raw `SELECT` from the table showing the values in question, or the `INSERT` statements needed to reproduce the effect?

Comment: Apparel Brand TotalPrice
Jeans Charly 2249.85
Jeans Lee  0.00
Jeans Lee        10497.90
Jeans NULL 12747.75
Shirt        Gucci  34539.90
Shirt     Tommy H 1070.00
Shirt        NULL  35609.90
NULL NULL 48357.65

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding your data into the original message so it formats nicely.  Now to find someone who can answer your question.  :-)

Comment: Thank you Steven I was looking for a way to edit but wasn't able thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ISNULL(Apparel, '**Grand Total**') as Apparel, 
    ISNULL(Brand, CASE WHEN apparel IS NULL THEN '**Grand Total**' ELSE '**Subtotal ' + apparel + '**' END) as Brand, 
    SUM (COALESCE((Quantity * Price),0)) AS TotalPrice
FROM #Sales
GROUP BY ROLLUP (Apparel, Brand)
```

Output using sample data:

```
Apparel         Brand               TotalPrice
pants           gucci               11000.00
pants           tommy               15000.00
pants           **Subtotal pants**  26000.00
shirt           gucci               3000.00
shirt           tommy               7000.00
shirt           **Subtotal shirt**  10000.00
**Grand Total** **Grand Total**     36000.00
```

Here's my sample data, if you'd like to try it out:

```
declare @t table (apparel varchar(100), brand varchar(100), Quantity int, Price numeric(12,2))
insert into @t values ('shirt', 'gucci', 10, 100)
insert into @t values ('shirt', 'gucci', 10, 200)
insert into @t values ('shirt', 'tommy', 10, 300)
insert into @t values ('shirt', 'tommy', 10, 400)
insert into @t values ('pants', 'gucci', 10, 500)
insert into @t values ('pants', 'gucci', 10, 600)
insert into @t values ('pants', 'tommy', 10, 700)
insert into @t values ('pants', 'tommy', 10, 800)
```